# Call function from preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The task is: parse html code and insert file modification date after each link on doc, xls etc.

There is function, that get this date from file:

```
function getFileModDate($file)
            {
                if (substr($file, 0, 1) == "/")
                {
                    $file = substr($file, 1, strlen($file));
                }

                $date = "";
                if(file_exists($file))
                {
                    $date = filemtime($file);
                    $date = trim(nDate($date));
                    $date = TAGFILEMDSTART.$date.TAGFILEMDSTOP;
                }
                return $date;
            }
```

Also there is a function that parses html and calls getFileModDate.

```
function docLinksToModDate($text)
            {
                if($text)
                {
                    $text = preg_replace("/<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*.(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf))\"\s(?!data-hide=\"true\")[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU", "\\0<em> Last edit: getFileModDate('\\1')</em>", $text );
                }
                return $text;
            }
```

But it doesn't work even with modifier **e** or preg_replace_callback().

Does anyone have any idea what to do in this case?

**UPD:** Whole php code

```
function docLinksToModDate($text)
            {
                if($text)
                {
                    $text = preg_replace("/<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*.(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf))\"\s(?!data-hide=\"true\")[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU", "\\0<em> Last edit: getFileModDate('\\1')</em>", $text );
                }
                return $text;
            }

            function getFileModDate($file)
            {
                if (substr($file, 0, 1) == "/")
                {
                    $file = substr($file, 1, strlen($file));
                }

                $date = "";
                if(file_exists($file))
                {
                    $date = filemtime($file);
                    $date = trim(nDate($date));
                    $date = TAGFILEMDSTART.$date.TAGFILEMDSTOP;
                }
                return $date;
            }

                $page_text = '<p>Sample text in Russian</p>
                <h2>List of documents</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="hello" href="http://www.td-vizavi.ru/docs/july_2014_jumping.doc" target="_blank">Document 1</a></li>
                    <li>Document 2 without file</li>
                    <li>Document 3 without file</li>
                </ul>
                <p><a href="/download/p_comp_fond_po.pdf" target="_blank">Request sample</a></p>
                <p>Description of our services. Collaboration is crucial in creative ventures, yet building a culture that allows it to flourish can be tricky—particularly in traditional, hierarchically minded organizations. But with a little tweaking, any space has the potential to become a hotbed of connected thinking. As Rosie Manning learned recently, true collaboration thrives in an environment built on trust, openness, and flexibility.</p>
                <p><a href="http://www.td-vizavi.ru/docs/june_person_2014_jumping.xls" data-hide="abracadabra">Letter sample</a></p>
                <p>Related information</p>
                <p><a href="http://www.td-vizavi.ru/docs/june_team_2014_jumping.xlsx" data-hide="true" target="_blank" >Document 4 </a></p>
                <ul >
                    <li><a href="/newstext6.html">Link to web page</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="/about.html">Link to web page 2</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="/certificate.html">Link to web page 3</a></li>
                </ul>';

            $page_text = docLinksToModDate($page_text );

            echo $page_text;
```

Comment: Please, provdie data examples (input, expectud output, actual output)

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea in mind by using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://ch2.php.net/preg_replace_callback), however, it is important to understand how the callback works. The function takes the following arguments: `preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $subject)` (and some optional parameters we can ignore for this case).

From php.net:

> **callback**
>
> A callback that will be called and passed an array of matched elements in the subject string. The callback should return the replacement string. This is the callback signature:
>
> `string handler ( array $matches )`

In other words, you cannot do something like `preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'my_function(\\1)', $subject)` but you are forced to pass the whole matching array to the function, and your callback will have to get the right array element(s).

A simple example:

```
 // Returns: file.TXT
 preg_replace_callback('/^.*\.([a-z]+)$/i', 'my_replacer', 'file.txt');

 function my_replacer($matches) {
      // Reference the matched group here, don't try
      // to pass it from preg_replace_callback
      return strtoupper($matches[1]);
 }
```

`$callback` may only contain the function's name to call, so if you want to append any other text to your replacement (like "Last modified:"), you'll have to do that in `$callback` itself.

Comment: Tried to change: 
`$text = preg_replace_callback("/<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*.(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf))\"\s(?!data-hide=\"true\")[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU", "myreplacer", $text );`  
and this: 
`function my_replacer($matches) {
     $note = $matches[0]."<em> Last edit: ".getFileModDate($matches[1])."</em>";
     return $note;
     }`
Doesn't work also.

Comment: @JuliaKotova Time for debugging – use `var_dump($matches)` in `my_replacer` and make sure you're getting what you think you are. If not, must be the regular expression; if you are, then it's something within `my_replacer`.